# Library not found for -lglfw3

Tags: c++, xcode, glfw

I am trying to learn openGL and the first step is to build and link the glfw3 library to my xcode project. However, I keep getting `ld: library not found for -lglfw3 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

I realized the problem is caused by having `libglfw3.a` in my `Link Binary With Libraries` in my project settings.

I got `libglfw3.a` from building glfw source code.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is `libglfw3.a` in a directory that xcode is looking for libraries in?

Comment: This is embarrassing....libglfw3.a is shown to be there in xcode BUT it's not actually there in computer directory. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem solved by checking if the lib file is actually in the xcode project. Those yellow folder things are actually not the real directory structure.